# Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ then which of the following are true?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ such that every non zero vector of $\mathbb{C^n}$ is an eigenvector of $A$. Then,
>
> 1. All eigen values of $A$ are equal.
> 2. All eigen values of $A$ are distinct.
> 3. $A=\lambda I$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ where $I$ is an $n\times n$ identity matrix.
> 4. If $\chi_A$ and $m_A$ denote the characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial respectively, then $\chi_A=m_A$.

Now for $4$, I know that $\chi_A=m_A$ implies the eigen space has dimension $1$, that is all the eigen-values are different. But how can I conclude if every non-zero vectors are eigen-vectors or not if this happens.

Again if $A=\lambda I$ then all the eigen values are same and every non-zero vector is an eigen vector. But I am confused to analyze it properly. Any help please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: It’s easy to see that if $A=\lambda I$, then every non-zero vector in $\Bbb C^n$ is an eigenvector of $A$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$, so it’s certainly possible for all of the eigenvalues of $A$ to be equal; this shows you that (2) and (4) are not necessarily true, while (1) and (3) can be true. All that remains is to decide whether (3) *must* be true (in which case (1) will also be true).

Suppose that $x,y\in\Bbb C^n$, $Ax=\lambda_1x$, and $Ay=\lambda_2y$, where $\lambda_1\ne\lambda_2$. Then

$$A(x+y)=Ax+Ay=\lambda_1x+\lambda_2y\;,$$

and $A(x+y)=\lambda(x+y)$ for some $\lambda\in\Bbb C$, so $\lambda x+\lambda y=\lambda_1x+\lambda_2y$, and therefore

$$(\lambda-\lambda_1)x=(\lambda_2-\lambda)y\;.$$

Observe that at least one of $\lambda-\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2-\lambda$ is non-zero and derive a contradiction, thereby showing that all eigenvalues of $A$ must be equal and hence that (1) must be true.

Now if all of the eigenvalues are equal to $\lambda$, say, so that $Ax=\lambda x$ for each $x\in\Bbb C^n$, then $A-\lambda I=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb C^n$, so what must $A$ be?

Comment: One question: why one of $\lambda-\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2-\lambda$ is non-zero? If one of them is non-zero then they are different and having same eigenvectors to different eigen-values will lead to a contradiction. But why they should be non-zero in the first place?

Comment: @Kushal: We're assuming that $\lambda_1\ne\lambda_2$, so $\lambda_1-\lambda\ne\lambda_2-\lambda$. Thus, if one of those differences is $0$, the other one is not, and neither is its negative.

Comment: Oh missed that point. Got it now.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Suppose that every nonzero vector is an eigenvector of $A$. We can recover algebraically the eigenvalue $\lambda$ of an eigenvector $\bf x$ using the fact that
$$\frac{\bar{\bf x}^T A {\bf x}}{\bar{\bf x}^T {\bf x}} = \frac{\bar{\bf x}^T \lambda {\bf x}}{\bar{\bf x}^T {\bf x}} = \lambda .$$
This suggests considering the (continuous) function $${\bf y} \mapsto \frac{\bar{\bf y}^T A {\bf y}}{\bar{\bf y}^T {\bf y}} ,$$ which, since every nonzero vector is an eigenvector, returns the eigenvalue of $\bf y$. What does continuity of this function imply if $A$ has two different eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, for the sake of illustration, that $n = 3$.

Let $e_1, e_2, e_3$ be the standard basis, so that $e_1 = (1, 0, 0)$, etc.

Remember (or compute) that the columns of $A$ are precisely its action on the basis vectors. But the basis vectors are also eigenvectors of $A$! So (e.g.) $Ae_1 = (\lambda_1, 0, 0)$ for some $\lambda_1$. Deduce that all the off-diagonal entries of $A$ are zero.

Now consider $A$ applied to the vector $e_1 + e_2 = (1, 1, 0)$. You'll get $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, 0)$. But this is *also* an eigenvector of $A$, so it is a multiple of $(1, 1, 0)$. What does that tell you about $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$?